# Keep moving table in jquery with continue click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to keep my table move when I click, for this I try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".next").click(function() { 
        var position = $(".slide_table").position().left;
        var movepos = parseInt(position) - parseInt(450) + 'px';    
        $('.slide_table').css('margin-left',movepos); 
     });
  });
</script>

<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<div class="slide">
   <table class="slide_table" style="border:1px solid gray; background:#CCCCCC">
```

When I click first time it works, So how can I keep it unless the right position is 0 or less than 450.

Thanks for help....

Comment: Isn't there some html missing?

Comment: There's no tag of class **next** I mean

Comment: next is in my html, It is working fine only for once....I want it continue

Comment: You're getting or setting the wrong CSS attributes. First you're getting position, and then you're setting margin. You should use the same property in both places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to move **10** px to the right for every click on the button, the code would be:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".next").click(function() { 
        var position = $('.slide_table').css('margin-left');
        var movepos = position + 10;    
        $('.slide_table').css('margin-left',movepos);
     });
  });
</script>
```

You don't need to add the string **'px'** at the end of the distance to move.

Comment: Thanks, But I want to move only entire table

Comment: Thanks, I used minus instead of plus('+'), and I got what I want..thankssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but:

If you want to move the table 450px (more) to the right side every time you click on the ".next"-button, then you can do that as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".next").click(function() { 
        var posLeft = $('.slide_table').position().left;
        var newPosLeft = posLeft - 450;

        $('.slide_table').css('left', newPosLeft + 'px');
    });
});
```